# php Session variable become undefined when click to another link

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
I have designed a bilingual website initially loading in Arabic language by declaring a session variable 'language'.The index page load correctly ,but when i click the button to convert the language i'am getting the session variable undefined.please help me to fix this issue.
```

This below function load the home page.here am getting the session variable in the home page.

```
public function index(){
    $_SESSION['page'] = 'Home';
    if(empty( $_SESSION["language"])){
        $_SESSION["language"] = "_ar";
    }
    $this->load->view('site'.$_SESSION["language"].'/index',$data);
```

}

```
    In the home page when i click the language convert button it call the below controller function,but the session variable become undefined in this controller function.
```

When i open in i

```
public function lang_change_ar_to_eng() {
    if ($_SESSION["language"] == "_en")
        $_SESSION["language"] = "_ar";
    else if($_SESSION["language"] == "_ar")
        $_SESSION["language"] = "_en";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    echo json_encode($_SESSION["language"]);
}
```

when i open in incognito window i got the session variables,i don't know what's the issue

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Please post your code! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The above comment notwithstanding: your problem is almost certainly that you are not calling `session_start()` during every request. Really, that should be the first line of code that runs for each request.

Comment: i have declared the session and a getting it in the home page of site,but become undefined in the controller when i click some link in the home page

Answer (score 1):

Most of Session errors are come from "Not declared **session_start()**"

You can check session is alive by below code.

```
echo session_id();
```

If that prints Null or empty string, that means session is closed.

Comment: i got a string..but session variable is undefined

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by using php version 7.2 on your server

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can show us some code. I think you have a wrong configuration.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment.